# Oracle SUM( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR WITH DECIMAL NUMBER

Tags: oracle, sum, decimal, regexp-substr

I have query like this

```
SELECT SUM( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( '2,0,0,0,0,0,8.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) ) ) AS SUM_TOTAL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( '2,0,0,0,0,0,8.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '\d+' );
```

AND MY RESULT IS 46, THE DECIMAL NUMBER (8.36) IS COUNTED AS SINGLE NUMBER LIKE (2 + 8 + 36) = 46.

I'M TRYING TO GET RESULT (2 + 8.36) = 10.36

IS IT POSSIBLE TO GET THIS RESULT ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You are only looking for non-negative integers (`\d+` means "one or more consecutive digits) - so, in addition to decimal numbers, you will also get wrong results if your string includes **negative** numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imstead of  `'\d+'` you will need to skip the comma.

Use `'[^,]+'`

So you query will be

I have query like this

```
SELECT SUM( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( '2,0,0,0,0,0,8.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ) ) ) AS SUM_TOTAL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( '2,0,0,0,0,0,8.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', ',' ) + 1;
```

Comment: What will happen to all the commas though?

Comment: Thanks but its returning ORA-01722  invalid number

Comment: Ok. I misinterpreted it with space

Comment: @dj_killer13 check now

Comment: Your explanation of your solution (in words) still says "skip space". You need to fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your string is a comma-separated list of **numbers**, including decimal numbers, negative numbers, numbers in exponential notation etc., possibly surrounded by whitespace, you can modify the query by using `[^,]+` instead of `\d+` (in both places). This selects all substrings of consecutive non-comma characters at a time, instead of all substrings of consecutive digits at a time.